# Is it possible to have a camera preview AND scan barcodes in Ionic/Cordova?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, camera

So I'm currently swimming across the web to try to investigate what already exists for which are compatible for Cordova/Ionic/AngularJS on iOS and Android only; just below is a quick view of what I've come across, then I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve. I've come across [cordova-plugin-camera-preview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview), which is absolutely ideal for the approach I would like to take; basically, embed it into my HTML without leaving my app. And I've also come across [quaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) which appears to be an interesting barcode scanner. Now I have used [cordovaBarcodeScanner](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/) but this appears to exit my application which isn't my ideal approach.

## What I am trying to achieve

Within my Ionic/Cordova mobile app, I am trying to achieve a live preview barcode scanner. So the idea is I would navigate to a page in my app which would instigate an embedded camera view and provide a live feed of what can be seen via my camera (what [cordova-plugin-camera-preview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview) provides is perfect for this approach) but of course this plugin does not provide any barcode (EAN) scanning capabilities. So at this point I found quaggaJS which seems like a good approach, however, I'm currently failing to get quaggaJS to work with my Cordova project which is a shame.

Would what I'm trying to achieve already exist, or is it possible to get the two plugins I'm referring to, to work with a Cordova project?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [QR Scanner Ionic Native Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/qr-scanner/)
but since it is only configured to scan QRCodes you must edit
the source to add the required barcode formats.

For Android edit the following file: /platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/bitpay/cordova/qrscanner/QRScanner.java
After Line 457:

```
formatList.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
// add your [BarcodeFormat][2] here.
```

For IOS edit the following file: 
/platforms/ios/yourapp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/QRScanner.swift

Line 156:

```
metaOutput!.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr, ... comma_seperated_formats_here]
```

You must also edit line 250:

```
if ( (found.type == (AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr) && found.stringValue != nil) )
```

Like so:

```
if ( (found.type == (AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr) && found.stringValue != nil) ||
    (found.type == (AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13) && found.stringValue != nil) || ..... )
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort for your response, I hope it helps others experiencing a similar issue. In my case this issue is no longer relevant for me as I've moved to Xamarin - also the original project was done with Ionic V1 and AngularJS so I don't believe your solution would have worked for my old project.

Comment: Thanks John, this helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What I found so far is the Scandit SDK who provides what you want, but it is paid and kinda expensive.

What I did so far was using this library you mentioned and the qrcode javascript library to decode the picture I get from the camera-preview, but it is not as fast as Scandit. If you find something better let us know.